# Tricky Indented Contour Integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3/4}}{(x^2+1)^2} \ dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> I am trying to evaluate the integral  $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3/4}}{(x^2+1)^2} \ dx,$$ by finding a suitable branch of $z^{3/4}$ and integrating the function $z\rightarrow z^{3/4}/(z^2+1)^2$ around the contour below:

$\hskip2in$[image]

I am unsure of how to deal with the branch cut. I know that $w^{1/n}$ is not differentiable for $(-\infty,0]$, but I am unsure what to do, as the contour above includes the negative real axis.

So far, I have show by the ML lemma that for $r<1<R$, $$\int_{\Gamma_1} f(z) \ dz\rightarrow 0 \ \text{as} \ R\rightarrow\infty.$$ Similarly, $$\int_{\Gamma_2} f(z) \ dz\rightarrow 0 \ \text{as} \ r\rightarrow 0.$$ I am having trouble solving the line segments. For $0<\delta<\frac{\pi}{2}$, I have shown that as $\delta\rightarrow 0$, the sum of both line segments equals $0$... but this cannot be correct.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try $f(z)=\frac{(-z)^{3/4}}{(z^2+1)^2}$, where $w^\alpha$ is the principal branch

Comment: Is $f(z)$ defined in the contour (besides $z=\pm i$)?

Comment: Cool, that is neat! But without such prior knowledge, this is ultimately unhelpful.

Comment: It can be simply done by Beta function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the branch cut as the **positive** real axis. Then you have a branch of
$z^{3/4}$ given by $re^{it}\mapsto r^{3/4}e^{3it/4}$ for $0\le t<2\pi$.
By continuity, on the "lower" horizontal segment of your contour $x^{3/4}$ becomes
$x^{3/4}e^{3\pi i/2}=-ix^{3/4}$.

Alternatively avoid the branch cut by making a preliminary substitution
$x=y^4$ or $x=e^y$.

Comment: If we take our branch cut as the positive real axis, how do we use the residue theorem to find $\int_\Gamma f(z) \ dz$, where $\Gamma$ is the join of all the contours?

Comment: The contour surrounds poles at $\pm i$. Compute the residues there.

Comment: I am a little confused. Does the negative real axis pose any concern? With out contour orientated in such a way, don't we want to somehow remove the negative real axis as $\sqrt{z}$ is not analytic here?

Comment: If we take the **positive** real axis as the branch cut, then $z^{3/4}$ is analytic in the left half-plane.

Comment: This is what I don't understand, why is this so? It is probably very obvious, but it is not for me.

Comment: @Bell note that $z^{3/4}=\exp\left(\frac34\ln z\right)$. So setting $\ln z$ with the branch cut at the positive real axis then $\ln z$ is holomorphic in $\Bbb C\setminus[0,\infty)$, so $z^{3/4}$ is also holomorphic in this region

Comment: Oh I see. So by determining a branch cut for $\ln(z)$, we're removing where $\ln(z)$ is not analytic? For instance, if we chose a branch cut to be the positive imaginary axis, then $\ln(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}$\ $[0,i\infty)$ (abuse of notation, but $i\infty$ just refers to the $k^{th}$ term on the positive imaginary axis)?

Answer (score 0):

$z^{\frac{3}{4}}=\exp(\frac{3}{4}\ln z)$

Below x-axis $\int_\infty ^0\frac{\exp(\frac{3}{4}\ln x+2\pi i)}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{ix^{\frac{3}{4}}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx$

So sum of the two path parallel to the x-axis is $(1+i)\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{\frac{3}{4}}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx$